# Database: relationship among multiple tables

Tags: database, database-design, schema, relational-database, database-relations

A worker need to pass controlTests. 
Each test consists on  50 controls divided on 5 categories, 
Ex:

- Category1: "Fire Security".
- Controls: "Extinguisher","Emergency
  exit","fire-fighting services"
- Category2: "Anti-thief system".....

It's possible to add on the future more Categories. Also it's possible to add more Controls to existing or  new categories.

For every control a worker must fill 3 checkcontrols

Ex:

- **Category1:** "Fire Security".
- **Control1:** "Extinguisher"
- Is checked daily? (true-false)
- Has been used the last year?(true-false)
- Importance level (1 to 5)

The system will be thousand of workers passing many controlTests every week.

These are my model tables

```
**controlCategory Table:**  PK: idCategory
idCategory | name | ...
1          | Fire security
2          | Anti thief system

**controlSubCategory Table:**      PK: idSubCategory
idSubCategory | idCategory | name             | ...
1             | 1          | Extinguisher
2             | 1          | Emergency exit
3             | 2          | Alarm

**controlTest Table:**           PK: idControlTest + idSubCategory
idControlTest | idSubCategory | CheckedDaily | UsedLastYear | Importance
1             | 1             |true          | false        |2
1             | 2             |true          | true         |2
1             | 3             |true          | false        |4
1             | 4             |false         | false        |3
1             | 5             |false         | true         |3
.......
1             | 50            |true          | true         |5
2             | 1             |false         | false        |1
2             | 2             |true          | false        |2
2             | 3             |true          | true         |4


**workerTest Table:**   PK: idControlTest
idControlTest | idWorker
1             |100
2             |323
3             |15
4             |255
5             |100
```

In terms of speed and efficiency, would you consider this schema as valid or do you change anything on it?